# Summing Page Break Groups

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Basically, I’m trying to create an SSRS report for all of our branches and their managers. Please note, each manager is responsible for more than one branch, and I’ve included page breaks between  each distinct branch (I’m grouping on branchID, and Branch Manager Name). To exemplify John Smith, is responsible for managing 2 branches and therefore, there are 2 separate pages in my report for each of John’s branches. What I’m trying to do now, is to SUM those to branches together on another page and repeat the same logic for all the other branch managers and their branches.  To make it more clear:

PAGE 1

John Smith – Branch 1

PAGE 2

John Smith- Branch 2

PAGE 3

John Smith (Both branches SUMMED up together)

PAGE 4

John Johnson – Branch 1

PAGE 5

John Johnson – Branch 2

PAGE 6

John Johnson  (Both branches SUMMED up together)

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a sub report that takes the BranchID as a parameter.

Within this subreport create a table that group by brand just as your current report does now.

Under this, create a separate table that is grouped only by Manager (You can use the same dataset as the source).

Once this report is done, create a new master report.

Create a dataset that only contains a list of distinct Branches. Add a table to this with just a single column and row. Set the dataset for this table to point to the dataset you just created.

Within this table, right click the cell and choose "Insert -> Subreport". Right-click the new subreport placeholder and choose "Properties". Set the subreport to point to your subreport we created earlier and set the parameter to be the BranchID from your dataset.

This will then call the subreport once for each branch.

You may have to set page breaks in the master report, on the table's 'details' row group to 'between'